# Call Fragment Method in an Activity getting NPE

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I would like to call method of `MainFragment.java` from `MainActivity.java`

Here what I have tried:

**MainActivity.java**

```
MainFragment mainFragment;

........

mainFragment = new MainFragment();

.........

mainFragment.deom();
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
public void deom() {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Demo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

**Log**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
at com.example.x.b(Unknown Source)
at com.example.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2633)
at android.support.v4.b.ao.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.app.t.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.n.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.n.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
```

May I know where I am doing mistake ? What I have missed ? Why I am getting NPE.

Comment: You have create instance of `MainFragment` first...

Comment: @Selvin this is not the duplicate one

Comment: @ByeBye tried same, check updated code and log above, still getting same issue...

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize MainFargment.

```
MainFragment mainFragment = (MainFragment) getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.theId);

mainFragment.deom();
```

Comment: I forgot to initialize that's why I tapped your answer as useful, but I cannot accept because I am still getting same NPE... check updated code and log above

Comment: What about you eventually start putting some efforts in debugging own code?

Comment: @Sophie , well you are using fragment. I've updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Sophie , And if you use Support Fragment, then use "getSupportFragmentManager" instead of "getFragmentManager".